# How to assign member function to member function pointer with overloading?

Tags: c++, overloading

How can I assign member function which is overloaded to other member function (or function pointer) in C++?

My objective is to wrap member function. I have following code and it doesn't work because it has 2 "Do"s. What I want to do is wrapping `Do1` or `Do2` to `Do` with any `double *` or `double **`. Hence, I can run only `Do` and don't need to care about `Do1` or `Do2`. (Maybe, I should specify condition that need to be chosen between `Do1` and `Do2`.)

```
class Sample { 
    int (*Do)(double *arr);
    int (*Do)(double **arr);
    int Do1(double *arr);
    int Do1(double **arr);
    int Do2(double *arr);
    int Do2(double **arr);
};
```

Or do you have any suggestions for this objective?

Addition : For Thomas, function objects(functors) is a good idea, but it only resolves overloading. I want to choose function (ex, `Do1` or `Do2`). I have several prescribed functions and I can make choose one of them to `Do`. However, I also want to assign custom function to `Do`.
For example when I run `Do`, I could run `Do1`, `Do2`, or my own new customized function. (I should set what function will be executed when I make a instance)

and.. I can't use C++11 in my situation. (I want to, but my server has a older GCC versions)

Comment: Have you tried using function objects instead of function pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ill-formed and will NOT compile. You can overload function, but not objects! That is, you cannot have two pointers named 'Do' with different types. I can't recall perfectly, but MSVC would tell you something like this:

> 'Sample::Do' : redefinition; different basic types

If you want to do something like that, you can use flag:

```
class Sample
{
    int Do(double *arr);
    int Do(double **arr);
    int Do1(double *arr);
    int Do1(double **arr);
    int Do2(double *arr);
    int Do2(double **arr);

    void SetDoVersion(int version);

    int _do_version;
};
```

And 'Do' would look like this:

```
int Sample::Do(double *arr)
{
  //For more than 2-3 versions you could also use switch().
  if(this->_do_version == 1)
    return this->Do1(arr);
  else
    return this->Do2(arr);
}

int Sample::Do(double **arr)
{
  //same as above
}
```

SetDoVersion() sets currently 'installed' version:

```
void Sample::SetDoVersion(int version)
{
  this->_do_version = version;
}
```

This is probably the simplest solution for this task.

Comment: I know my code has a bug and I got a compiler's message. Your answer will be good choice, however if I want to add my customized function to ``Do`` this solution will not fit to me. thank you for your answer.